# Do Jquery have any plugin for Date & Time pick

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery datepicker in 24 hour pattern.

mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss

08-20-2010 14:45:33

I found so many date pickers in jquery , but no one is giving time!!!

Any body know about  both date and time picker.??
jquery jquery ui anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a good one.  I found a flexible textbox works best.

Nothing that did both date AND time.  I use the jQuery datepicker and for time I'm currently using this one call timebox, though I had to adjust it slightly for my needs to allow for things like 8p to return 20:00 instead of 8:00 and such

http://devblog.powerhour.at/jquery-timebox/

Comment: i found something here..
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/anytime
trying to implement it

Comment: @zod, I **HATE** having to use a mouse to enter things, if I'm doing data input, I want to be able to use the keyboard as well and just tab through all the fields, but, to each their own.

Comment: @Chad, the original timebox script is now unavailable. Could you perhaps put yours on github or something so its available again. It still seems there is no other good way to input time. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

this one's not to bad.
http://jonathonhill.net/2009-03-27/jquery-datetime-picker/

but really a date picker, and a textbox that parses time is your best bet.

i've used the time parser from here: http://www.phpied.com/javascript-time-input/
with some success,  be careful though it does funny things with 12:00.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little outside of what you are asking but you might want to also consider just getting rid of the datepicker and going with a library like date.js. It can parse almost any human readable date and warn you if it isn't one. Then you can let your users enter anything they want and so long as it is valid you are fine. If not you will be able to notify them. Plus it is eliminates the need for an extra ui element.

http://www.datejs.com/

Both of these are valid entries

june 3, 2010 22 = Thursday, June 03, 2010 10:00:00 PM

6/3/2010 10 pm = Thursday, June 03, 2010 10:00:00 PM

Just in case you weren't familiar with it I wanted to mention it. Once I found this I never look at date handling the same.